# Kibana 3 bettermap ploting lat/long in wrong location on map

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to use bettermap in Kibana 3 to see lat/long data. My geo location is shown in the map in Africa where as the lat/long I have specified are for US.

Any help on the same would be appreciated?

my mapping file is

`{"mappings" : {
        "livestats" : {
            "_source" : {
                "enabled" : true
            },
            "_timestamp" : {
                "enabled" : true
            },
            "_all" : {
                "enabled" : false
            },
            "properties" : {
                "state" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "store" : "yes" },
                "LatLng" : { "type" : "geo_point" , "index" : "analyzed", "store" : "yes"}
            }
        }
    }
}`

and dummy data is

```
{"create":{"_index":"livestats","_type":"livestats"}}
{"state":"CA","LatLng":[-118.252,34.0433]}
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using geopoint as an object ? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html#_lat_lon_as_properties_5

Answer (score 0):

Try with lonlat as the dummy data.
The tooltip on better map says: "geoJSON array! Long,Lat NOT Lat,Long"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to specify the full fieldname in Bettermaps (Kibana 3.0.0). The autosuggested fieldnames, when you preload the fieldname's of your index, are missleading.

Here is my suggestion: 
Replace the mapping of LatLon with:
     "LatLng" : { "type" : "geo_point"}

Make sure you comply with GeoJSON Specification: [lon,lat] and not [lat,lon]

In Kibana, use the following field:
    "livestats.LatLng"

That should do the trick!